# Get value from URL into sharepoint form textbox

Tags: url, text, sharepoint, parameters

I am trying to achieve URL parameter values and set those values on a form automatically. I have created a flow that will send the link to add new item to the required form. The link is of the form: "http://servername/sitename/Lists/listname/NewForm.aspx?Title=item1&PIC=Nameofapersn".

So, when one person click on this link they should get a new form with prefilled 'Title' textbox which have value 'Item1' automatically and same applicable for PIC field too. Which approach will be better for this? Can we do this with using flows?

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to do this.

You can find more on the below link

[How to get URL parameter using jQuery or plain JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/how-to-get-url-parameter-using-jquery-or-plain-javascript)